# Strip Google search URL to original clean url

Tags: php, string, search, hyperlink

I am looking for a function that takes a dirty google search URL and returns it clean, as the original URL, means the URL that will show up in your browser after you clicked on the search result and the redirection.
For example, convert this link: 
https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiiz-Xp4srYAhXOxqQKHTZeAPQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.usatoday.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw04_mIwjwWapfFyzAJqqpNW

To this: 
https://www.usatoday.com/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code? Errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 'exploding' the string.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiiz-Xp4srYAhXOxqQKHTZeAPQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.usatoday.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw04_mIwjwWapfFyzAJqqpNW';
$url = urldecode($url);
echo $url . '<br>'; //normal url
$url = explode('&',$url);
$url = str_replace('url=','',$url);
echo $url[9]; //the url is the 9th variable in the string/array
?>
```